# How do I receive this code in php? And how do I consume it?

Tags: soap

I'm working on a website project to consume a web service, how do I receive this in php and how do I consume it? Thank you for helping out. I need to connect to their API, send the XML file genrerated in my website and then receive the response. http://www.safaricom.co.ke/business/corporate/m-pesa-payments-services/m-pesa-api for the api

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:c2b="http://cps.huawei.com/cpsinterface/c2bpayment">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <c2b:C2BPaymentConfirmationRequest>
         <TransactionType>PayBill</TransactionType>
         <TransID>1234560000007031</TransID>
         <TransTime>20140227082020</TransTime>
         <TransAmount>123.00</TransAmount>
         <BusinessShortCode>12345</BusinessShortCode>
         <BillRefNumber>TX1001</BillRefNumber>
         <InvoiceNumber></InvoiceNumber>
         <OrgAccountBalance>12345.00</OrgAccountBalance>
<ThirdPartyTransID></ThirdPartyTransID>
<MSISDN>254722703614</MSISDN>
         <KYCInfo>
            <KYCName>[Personal Details][First Name]</KYCName>
            <KYCValue>Hoiyor</KYCValue>
        </KYCInfo>
        <KYCInfo>
            <KYCName>[Personal Details][Middle Name]</KYCName>
            <KYCValue>G</KYCValue>
        </KYCInfo>
        <KYCInfo>
            <KYCName>[Personal Details][Last Name]</KYCName>
            <KYCValue>Chen</KYCValue>
        </KYCInfo>
      </c2b:C2BPaymentConfirmationRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

My best advice is to use a WSDL to php generator such as [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) as you'll only deal with object to send the request then only deal with object when getting back the response. Using the generated SDK really eases consuming any SOAP Web Service. It uses the native SoapClient class (which is the first real starting point in this case if you wish to understand deeply the process).

Answer (score 0):

Safaricom has released M-Pesa APIs as RESTful APIs accessible through their [developer portal](https://developer.safaricom.co.ke) . You need not use the M-Pesa SOAP APIs.